# What does 'afx_msg' do? - MFC

Tags: c++, mfc

**Disclaimer:** I'm new to MFC and have basic knowledge of c++

**My question:**

I ran into the following code that was auto generated by Visual studio:

`afx_msg void OnBnClickedOk();`

what does `afx_msg` do and are there other like that?

---

As far as my knowledge goes, there are only a handful of access specifiers like : `public`, `private`, `protected`. There's also `virtual`.

I found an answer [here](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?68767-what-is-afx_msg-When-I-need-it) but it is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`afx_msg` is an empty macro #define'd in `afxwin.h`:

```
// Type modifier for message handlers
#ifndef afx_msg
#define afx_msg         // intentional placeholder
#endif
```

The code will compile and work the same with or without `afx_msg`, but it is used by convention as an indicator that the function is a message handler, and is required if using the class wizard, per [TN006: Message Maps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0812b0wa.aspx):

> ClassWizard requires that you use the afx_msg keyword in your message map handler declarations.

Comment: Can't think of other function modifiers offhand, but MFC does define a large number of macros. See for example [MFC Macros and Globals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2dch7fb.aspx) in particular the sections about [Run-Time Object Model Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f16k9f4y.aspx), [Exception Processing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e583tzca.aspx), [ATL and MFC String Conversion Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3.aspx) etc.

Answer (score 3):

The code in `afxwin.h` is just:

```
// Type modifier for message handlers
#ifndef afx_msg
#define afx_msg         // intentional placeholder
#endif
```

it is, or might have been, a help for the wizards to recognize the code.

It doesn't do anything else.

Comment: The Visual Studio contains "wizards" that help you manage the code, like adding a message handler in MFC. 10-15 years ago the source contained lots of markers to make it easier for the IDE to recognize certain parts. Nowadays it seems to work anyway.